# drawRect function not triggered when needDisplay is called

Tags: swift, macos, drawrect, setneedsdisplay

I am trying to create a custom class to build various graph views for the app eventually. The main class is the viewController class where I would like to present the graphs managed by the clGraph class. clGraph class will be used to process the data and create a graph view by vGraph class.

plotGraph function in the vGraphs is where I am struggling. It appears that the drawRect function is not called, however, setNeedsDisplay is called. Below is the test code that I have to understand and learn the basics. Requesting help to be able to draw a basic line on the targetView. Thank you.

```
class main : NSViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var targetView: NSView!
    
    func plotGraph(){
        let g = clGraphs()
        g.initialize(graphCanvas: targetView, controller: self)
        g.processData()
        g.plotline()
    }
}

class clGraphs {
    
    var controller = NSViewController()
    var graphCanvas = NSView()
    
    var lineData = [Float]()
    
    public func initialize (graphCanvas : NSView, controller : NSViewController) -> clGraphs{
        self.graphCanvas = graphCanvas
        self.controller = controller
        return self
    }
    
    public func plotline(){
        let lb = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 20))
        lb.stringValue = "Test" //works fine on the view
        graphCanvas.addSubview(lb)
        print(graphCanvas.frame) //works fine
        let g = vGraphs()
        g.graphCanvas = graphCanvas
        g.needsDisplay = true
    }
    
    public func processData(){
        //Some logic to update lineData
    }
}

class vGraphs: NSView{
    
    var graphCanvas = NSView()
    var lineData = [Float]()
    
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        print("In the draw rect function")
    }
    
    override func setNeedsDisplay(_ invalidRect: NSRect) {
        print("In the set needs display function")
        plotGraph()
    }
    
    func plotGraph(){
        graphCanvas.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor //works fine
        let aPath = NSBezierPath()
        aPath.move(to: NSPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
        aPath.line(to: NSPoint(x: 200, y: 200))
        aPath.lineWidth = 10
        aPath.close()
        aPath.stroke()
        // ERROR: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `graphCanvas.addSubview(g)`? If you override `setNeedsDisplay` and don't call `super` then the view doesn't draw. The drawing code should be in `draw` instead of `setNeedsDisplay`.

Comment: @Willeke Thank you for your response. I tried putting graphCanvas.addSubview(g) in the plotline(). It is still not triggering drawRect function. Interestingly setNeedsDisplay is called four times during the run time. Also plotGraph() is placed in the drawRect()

Comment: @Willeke By adding ** g.frame = graphCanvas.frame **  and then adding a subview 'graphCanvas.addSubview(g)' I was able to draw the line. By going over step by step, it looks like the rect dimensions were all zero when in the vGraph class, so I used 'frame' of the existing view 'graphCanvas'. Not sure if this is the right way though. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction to add the subview.

Comment: If you want `g` to be the same size as `graphCanvas` then do `g.frame = graphCanvas.bounds`. `frame` is in superview coordinates (from the outside), `bounds` is in view coordinates (from the inside)

Comment: @Willeke Thank you Willeke for helping me! I have learned something as I am new to Swift.